# EF Core 7.x with JSON column fails on 'add migration'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have a `Student` model class with a property that I want to save as JSON in the database. I am using .NET Core 7.x with EF Core 7.x and MySQL.

My `Student` model is simple:

```
public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentData> Data {get; set;} = new ();
}
```

The other object models related:

```
public class StudentData
{
    public virtual Day Day { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentValue Value { get; set; }
}

public class StudentValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public int DateOfMonth { get; set; }
    public string DayHE { get; set; }
    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

My `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().OwnsMany(
        entity => entity.Data, builder =>
        {
            builder.ToJson();
            builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Day);
            builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Value);
        });
}
```

Now, I am trying to create new migration using the following:

```
dotnet-ef migrations add AddStudentModel
```

but it failed with:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The full error message:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
2023-07-10 16:40:54.2833|0|INFO|Program|Server is running in "Development" mode, on port 5053 |Program.<Main>$
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.RelationalModel.CreateTableMapping(IRelationalTypeMappingSource relationalTypeMappingSource, IEntityType entityType, IEntityType mappedType, StoreObjectIdentifier mappedTable, RelationalModel databaseModel, List`1 tableMappings, Boolean includesDerivedTypes, Nullable`1 isSplitEntityTypePrincipal)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.RelationalModel.AddTables(RelationalModel databaseModel, IEntityType entityType, IRelationalTypeMappingSource relationalTypeMappingSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.RelationalModel.Create(IModel model, IRelationalAnnotationProvider relationalAnnotationProvider, IRelationalTypeMappingSource relationalTypeMappingSource, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.RelationalModel.Add(IModel model, IRelationalAnnotationProvider relationalAnnotationProvider, IRelationalTypeMappingSource relationalTypeMappingSource, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelRuntimeInitializer.InitializeModel(IModel model, Boolean designTime, Boolean prevalidation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(IModel model, Boolean designTime, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 validationLogger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Running the same command with `-v` (for verbose) doesn't reveal too much...

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`.

See: [Does ToJson not supported? Getting exception](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1779)

Answer (score 0):

What is `BaseEntity`? And is there any property that can be used as a primary key? such as `Id`

I added `Id` in `BaseEntity` and it can migrate successfully.

```
public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentData> Data { get; set; } = new();
}

public class StudentData
{
    public virtual Day Day { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentValue Value { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class StudentValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().OwnsMany(
      student=> student.Data, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
      {
          ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
          ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(contactDetails => contactDetails.Day);
          ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(contactDetails => contactDetails.Value);
      });
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by importing `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Json.Microsoft`

and setting it up like this:

```
optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
    connectionString,
    serverVersion,
    options => options.UseMicrosoftJson())
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Upgrade to the upper Net version in Visual Studio. It works with NET 8.0 with no issues.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76807092/861716). It's not a .net-related  issue.